# Trying to convert rewriterule regex into php regex with minimal regex modification

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteRule ^galleries/?([0-9]{4})?([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?(image|thumbnail|page)?s?/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+)?\.?(.+)?$ whatever [NC,L]
```

When someone visits any of:

```
http://example.com/galleries/20140630ABC/image/x1.jpg
http://example.com/galleries/20140520DEF/image/x22.jpg
```

The regex is processed correctly and forwards the url to "whatever".

I then tried to create the PHP version of my regex with minimal modification. This was my first attempt using the test string on the 2nd line of my code:

```
<?php
$is="galleries/20140630ABC/image/x1.jpg";
$p='^galleries/?([0-9]{4})?([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?(image|thumbnail|page)?s?/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+)?\.?(.+)?$';
echo preg_match($p,$is,$mat);
print_r($mat);
?>
```

The above code produces this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in /path/to/code.php on line 4
```

I then surrounded my regex with slashes inside quotes. My code then is this:

```
    <?php
    $is="galleries/20140630ABC/image/x1.jpg";
    $p='/^galleries/?([0-9]{4})?([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?(image|thumbnail|page)?s?/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+)?\.?(.+)?$/';
    echo preg_match($p,$is,$mat);
    print_r($mat);
    ?>
```

I received this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' in /path/to/code.php on line 4
```

I'm probably using the wrong function, but I want to modify my regex as little as possible from the one I wrote in the apache configuration file when evaluating it in PHP. How do I fix this? or is it even possible?

Comment: Escape special characters. Such as the delimiter in the regex itself

Comment: You might want to change your delimiter, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: changing delimiter partially works for me, but it has not picked up all the elements, particularly the `(image|thumbnail|page)` part ... Never mind now.... I think I got it working because of the delimiter change. I had to make the casing of both the string to test and regex the same.

Comment: *preg_match **_all()***

Answer (score 1):

With `\` to escape `/`, it should be better. Try this :

```php
$re = "/^galleries\\/?([0-9]{4})?([0-9]{2})?([0-9]{2})?([a-z0-9_-]+)?\\/?(image|thumbnail|page)?s?\\/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+)?\\.?(.+)?$/"; 
$str = "galleries/20140630ABC/image/x1.jpg"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($str);
```

check it here : https://regex101.com/r/vV2vC5/1